# window.external in Webview in Mac

Tags: javascript, objective-c, macos, webview

In my webview  i have a local webpage loaded, something like this,

function sendvalue(type, state)
         {
              window.external.sendMessage(type,state);
         }
      
    
    
      Show WC

In the webview its loaded like this,

```
-(void)gotWebview:(NSString *)pHTMLDoc{
    [[[self pWebView] mainFrame] loadHTMLString:pHTMLDoc baseURL:nil];
    [[self pWebView] setEditable:NO];
    [[self pWebView] setNeedsDisplay:YES];
    [[self pWebView] setFrameLoadDelegate:self];
    [[self pWebView] setEditingDelegate:self];
}
```

To handle window.external, i tried to do something like this,

```
scriptObject = [self windowScriptObject];
[scriptObject setValue:self forKey:@"window.external"];
```

Even i tried with this one too,

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didClearWindowObject:(WebScriptObject *)windowScriptObject forFrame:(WebFrame *)frame
{
    [windowScriptObject setValue:self forKey:@"window.external"];
}
```

and the function to bind Objective C and JS

```
+(NSString*)webScriptNameForSelector:(SEL)sel
{
    if(sel == @selector(sendMessage:))
        return @"sendMessage";
    return nil;
}

+ (BOOL)isSelectorExcludedFromWebScript:(SEL)sel
{
    if(sel == @selector(sendMessage))
        return NO;
    return YES;
}
```

After this, i was expecting if button is pressed , it should execute sendMessge written in the Objective C, but its not hitting,

Also need to mention, i will get the page from server, so its not possible to change it.
basically i would like to know how to bind window.external in my webview, so i can hook these call, 
I have seen [Embedded Webkit - script callbacks how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288582/embedded-webkit-script-callbacks-how) but didn't get what i was expecting.